# Setting ID of symbol in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arccatalog, annotation

I have an annotation layer where each annotation has it's own font size, position etc.

[image]

Accidentally in ArcCatalog I deleted Symbol with an ID 0. That caused annotations to display as red rectangles. Now if I update SymbolID column with existing Symbol ID then annotation is displayed, but it automatically updates most columns in that row (for example FontSize). I absolutely need to keep existing values.

Is there any method of defining Symbol with ID=0 or to update SymbolID column without auto updating other columns?

I tried SymbolID -1, but ArcMap will not let me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce deleting Symbol 0 from an annotation class (I'm using 10.4, and it looks like deleting symbol 0 has been prohibited), but I would try using the [Append Annotation Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000029000000) tool to try and regenerate the annotation feature class provided you have a Standard or higher license.

Comment: I use the same version. Just edit Default class in Annotation Classes tab. It will create new Default Symbol in Annotation tab with ID=1. Old Symbol will be renamed to Default_old and it will have ID=0. Now you can delete Default_old symbol. BTW., I cannot edit Symbol with ID=0, everything in properties is disabled.